# Django w/ sqlite3 CharField crashing on special character: "Rüppell's Vulture"

Tags: python, django, csv, unicode, sqlite

Django verision 1.9, DB backend: sqlite3.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to handle this error.  I am importing the master bird species list ([available here](http://www.worldbirdnames.org/ioc-lists/master-list-2/)) into a set of Django models.  I had the import going well, but it is crashing when I try to save this value: `Rüppell's Vulture` into the model.  The target field is defined like this:

```
species_english = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is there error:

> ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a
>   text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory =
>   str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your
>   application to Unicode strings.

I was reading through [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/unicode/) about unicode strings.  Which starts off beautifully like this:

> Django natively supports Unicode data everywhere. Providing your
>   database can somehow store the data, you can safely pass around
>   Unicode strings to templates, models and the database.

Also looking up [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C) about this character: `ü`, it has representation is both unicode and utf-8.

The method for saving this string to the DB is very straight-forward, I am simply parsing the CSV file using `csv.reader`:

```
new_species = Species(genus=new_genus, species=row[4], species_english=row[7])
```

Where the error-throwing string is contained in `row[7]`.  What am I missing about why the database will not allow this character?

**UPDATE**

here is the content of the whole script importing the data:

```
import csv
from birds.models import SpeciesFile, Order, Family, Genus, Species, Subspecies

csv_file = str(SpeciesFile.objects.all()[0].species_list)

#COLUMNS
#0 - Order
#1 - Family Scientific
#2 - Family (English)
#3 - Genus
#4 - Species
#5 - SubSpecies


with open("birds/media/"+csv_file.split('/')[1], 'rU') as c:
    Order.objects.all().delete()
    Family.objects.all().delete()
    Genus.objects.all().delete()
    Species.objects.all().delete()
    Subspecies.objects.all().delete()
    reader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    ini_rows = 4
    for row in reader:
        if ini_rows > 0:
            ini_rows -= 1
            continue
        if row[0]:
            new_order = Order(order=row[0])
            new_order.save()
        elif row[1]:
            new_fam = Family(order = new_order, family_scientific=row[1], family_english=row[2])
            new_fam.save()
        elif row[3]:
            new_genus = Genus(family = new_fam, genus=row[3])
            new_genus.save()
        elif row[4]:
            print row[4]
            new_species = Species(genus=new_genus, species=row[4], species_english=row[7])
            new_species.save()
        elif row[5]:
            print row[5]
            new_subspecies = Subspecies(species=new_species, subspecies=row[5])
            new_subspecies.save()
```

And here are the models.py file definitions:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class SpeciesFile(models.Model):
    species_list = models.FileField()

class Order(models.Model):
    order = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order

class Family(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    family_scientific = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    family_english = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.family_english+" "+self.family_scientific

class Genus(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genus

class Species(models.Model):
    genus = models.ForeignKey(Genus, default=None)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    species_english = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.species+" "+self.species_english

class Subspecies(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    subspecies = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subspecies
```

Comment: Please show the context of that code, including the part that is reading the CSV.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Thanks, I included the import script and also the models.py content.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django CharField is a character-oriented format. You need to pass it Unicode strings.

CSV is a byte-oriented format. When you read data out of a CSV file you get byte strings.

To get from bytes to characters you have to know what encoding was used when the original characters were turned into bytes as the CSV file was exported. Ideally that would be UTF-8, but if the file has come out of Excel it probably won't be. Maybe it's Windows-1252 (‘ANSI’ code page for Western European installations). Maybe it's something else.

(Django/Python 2 lets you get away with writing byte strings to Unicode properties when you have only ASCII bytes in it (bytes 0–127) because those have the same mapping in a lot encodings. ASCII is a ‘best guess’ at Do What I Mean, but it's not reliable and Python 3 prefers to raise errors if you try.)

So:

```
new_order = Order(order=row[0].decode('windows-1252'))
```

or, to decode the whole row at once:

```
row = [s.decode('windows-1252') for s in row]
```

Comment: Your `windows-1252` encoding didn't work, but you were right about the encoding problem, of course.  I ended up opening the xls file with google docs and then downloading a csv from there.  It worked with that new file without specifying the encoding.  I have chinese version of excel on my Mac, so it must be some strange encoding.